# API doesn't work, using Docker and ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core-webapi

I made an ASP.NET Core web API that pings a Mongodb and a docker container for it. The web api calls work when not using docker but returns a Not Found error when I do use it. I think it has something to do with the ports I'm running on but I'm not sure cause this is the first time I've used docker.

In the command prompt I do:

`docker build -t projectname .`

And then I run the image with

`docker run -p 8080:80 projectname`

Once running, if I make a call to http://localhost:8080/api/classname, I get a Not Found error with the message "this is my invalid message" so it seems like my docker container IS running. When I make a call to http://localhost:8080/api/classname?id=1 (this is a valid id), I still get a Not Found error but don't get the "this is my invalid message" text.

ClassNameController API GET:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClassNameController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetDescendents(int id)
        {
            var mongoDbService = new MongoDbService();

      
            try
            {
                var node = mongoDbService.GetTreeNodeById(id);

                if (node == null)
                {
                    return NotFound("this is my invalid message");
                }
                else
                {
                    //stuff happens
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Dockerfile:

```
See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj", "ProjectName/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ProjectName"
RUN dotnet build "ProjectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectName.dll"]
```

launchSetting.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
      "sslPort": 8080
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "DockerAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the url of the API you are trying to call?

Comment: I'm trying to call `http://localhost8080/api/classname?id=1`

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/treenode?id=1

Answer (score 2):

The web API and mongo service are likely to be on different networks when you use it in a docker container, considering that you have not defined it.

A quick way to solve this is to change the `localhost` from your mongo connection string from your IP number, in your `appsettings`, like this:

```
"ConnectionString":"mongodb://192.168.0.27:27017"
```

Pay attention, in your Dockerfile you don't define the environment, in this case, your app in docker will use the production `appsettings` and not your `appsettings.Development`.

If you prefer up both of then in a compose, you'll can define a network for all your services and then use just the name of the service on the connection string, like this:

```
 "ConnectionString":"mongodb://mongo"
```

Example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    networks:
      - mynetwork  

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  webapi:
    container_name: webapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./YourProject/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    links:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

And then:

```
docker-compose up
```